# Observing a Singleton's data from a view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton, key-value-observing

I'm trying to observe a string in a Singleton from a view controller.

In my view controller I do this in viewDidLoad:

```
  Singleton *singleton = [Singleton sharedSingleton];
    [singleton addObserver:self
                    forKeyPath:@"testString"
                       options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                       context:nil];
```

..and this code is at the bottom of the view controller:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"recieved");
}
```

The testString, in the Singleton, is changed 5 seconds later, but the observeValueForKeyPath is not called.. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you changing the string pointer or mutating a mutable string?

Comment: I'm doing testString = @"sdfsdfdf"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use properties e.g. `self.testString = newString` instead of `testString = newString` or KVO will not work.

Comment: @cannyboy - I'd recommend reading through the [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA) so you can see what's going on behind the scenes here.